# Type casting the `Object` type variables

Tags: java, casting, types, type-conversion

I need to call a function with the following signature.

`createColumn (N name, V value, Serializer<N> nameSerializer, Serializer<V> valueSerializer)`

I want to pass variables of type `Object` which might have been assigned values of integer or  string, I want the type casting to be performed automatically..according to the values that I assigned to Object type variables instead of explicit cast like this:-

`Object object1= "MY_AGE";`
 // string value assigned to to object type variable

`Object object2= 31;`   // integer value assigned to object type variable

`createColumn ((String)object1, (int)object2, ....);` // Since the datatype of *object1* & *object2* would not be same everytime while I am calling this function in a *for* loop, I want that it should automatically cast according to the value I assign to it.* So I am seeking something like this, if possible:-

`createColumn (object1, object2, ....);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the following since you don't want to check at compile time that the types match,

```
createColumn(object1, object2, (Serializer)serializer1, (Serializer)serializer2);
```

EDIT: This compiles for me (with an "Unchecked" warning)

```
interface Serializer<T> { }
public static <N,V> void createColumn (N name, V value, Serializer<N> nameSerializer, Serializer<V> valueSerializer) {
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws  NoSuchFieldException {
    Object object1 = "hi";
    Object object2 = 31;
    Serializer<String> serializer1 = null;
    Serializer<Integer> serializer2 = null;
    createColumn(object1, object2, (Serializer) serializer1, (Serializer) serializer2);
}
```

Comment: method createStringColumn in class `me.prettyprint.hector.api.factory.HFactory cannot be applied to given types
  
  
  **required:** java.lang.String,java.lang.String
**found:** java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object`

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question is not about casting (which deals with compile-time declared types), but conversion (which deals with runtime type of objects).

Consider using `String.valueOf()` method for your `Object` arguments. For both `Integer` and `String` it will produce their `String` representation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible, you have given the variable a type object and i'm not aware of any way to determine if it is really an int or string unless you use some ugly logic to see what characters the value consists of but that isn't going to be fool proof unless the value will always be either an integer or a string.

Do you need to pass integers or can everything just be passed as a string?

Comment: I need to pass both depending on scenario..that is more of runtime choice

Comment: If it will be one or the other and not a more complex object then create a function IsInt(String yourinput) that takes the value as a string and checks each character, if each charater is in 0-9 then return true else return false